# Converting QMap<QString, QString> to Json string results empty

Tags: qt

I have a function defined and used as this:

```
// usage:
QMap<QString, QString> map = ...;
foo(map);

// defination:
QString stringMapToJson(const QMap<QString, QString>& arg) {
    QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(arg);
    JsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(v);
    ...
}
```

Then I realized `v` is empty.

1. Is there a method to convert `QMap<String, QString>` to `QMap<String, QVariant>`, so above `v` could be valid?
2. Why above `v` is empty? I read people were saying `QVariant` and `qMetaData`, I don't understand given the following valid, why `QString` have a `qMetaData` problem:

```
QString s = "";
QVariant v = s;
```

(A Java programmer starts her pleasant C++ journey.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this. The first is to convert your map to a `QMap<QString, QVariant>` like you mentioned:

```
QByteArray stringMapToJson1(const QMap<QString, QString>& arg)
{
    QVariantMap vmap;
    for(auto it = arg.cbegin(); it != arg.cend(); ++it)
    {
        vmap.insert(it.key(), it.value());
    }
    const QVariant v = QVariant::fromValue(vmap);
    const QJsonDocument doc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(v);
    return doc.toJson();
}
```

Alternatively, you can build the json object directly from the map. In this case it's the same amount of code:

```
QByteArray stringMapToJson2(const QMap<QString, QString>& arg)
{
    QJsonObject jObj;
    for(auto it = arg.cbegin(); it != arg.cend(); ++it)
    {
        jObj.insert(it.key(), it.value());
    }
    QJsonDocument doc;
    doc.setObject(jObj);
    return doc.toJson();
}
```

This seems like a stylistic choice and I am unsure which would be faster. Both produce the same output.

One thing to note: The conversion from `QString` to `QVariant` is predefined in Qt, so the first method works fine. For objects of your own classes you would have to register that type and provide a suitable conversion which can be a bit tough to get right. In the second method you could do this conversion inline in the loop.